# I want to split column categories into unique categories list using for loop and normal function

Tags: python, database, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

**I have a column that has a lot of categories together like (Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller) (Action Adventure Science Fiction Thriller) (Action|Crime|Thriller)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8FHs.png) as in the below picture..I want to create a function that creats a list with all unique values on column then count them later for every value. see picture please I want something like List = [Action,Thriller,Adventure.....]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you are reading these columns into Python as a string. A way you could easily split this string into the list you desire is to use the string method `split()`. Here is some example code.

```py
def get_genres(row):
    """
    :param row: a string containing a set of genres seperated by '|'
    :return: a list of strings containing the genres of the row
    """
    return row.split('|')
```

Comment: it gives me error with : AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' and what i want is to iterate over the text and add every category before the | to a list

Comment: so the correction just would be adding str(row).split to solve the problem